# Create flash message from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm polling a long running process for success/failure in javascript. If the process fails, I need it to navigate to specific page and display a `flash['alert']`. I'm navigating to a new page using `window.location.href`, but I can't figure out how to create a `flash['alert']` from js. As a complete temporary hack, I'm passing an error message as a url parameter. Then in my controller `new` action, I check the parameter and create `flash['alert']` if an error exists. I don't like this solution and I'm assuming there is a cleaner way to do it.

```
function checkReportStatus() {
  var report_id = $(".report").data("report-id");
  $.get('/reports/' + report_id + '/check_report_status', function(report_status) {
      if (report_status === 'completed') {
        location.reload();
      }
      else if (report_status === 'error' || report_status === 'failed') {
        window.location.href = "new?error=ERROR_MESSAGE";
      }
      else {
        console.log("Report generation in progress...");
        setTimeout(checkReportStatus, 3000);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you need to handle all the above in JS? Why can't you just poll a Controller action which can decide to render a new page with a message.

Comment: `check_report_status` is a controller action that I'm polling. It returns `report_status`. I tried to add a `redirect_to` in the action, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe because it's a GET request? Also, this is a delayed_job background task, so I think the controller action is being called from the worker, which maybe can't redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by moving the `check_report_status` code to a controller action and used `render` instead of `redirect_to`.

```
def check_report_status
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    flash[:error] = "Report error"
    render :js => "window.location = 'PATH'"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('element').effect('highlight', {color:'#XXXXXX'},1500);` produces a decent flashing effect, since you do mention the use of jQ in your tags.